# Is there any way to use AREL for custom associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, arel

```
model Post
  # ActiveRecord associations have tons of options that let
  # you do just about anything like:
  has_many :comments
  has_many :spam_comments, :conditions => ['spammy = ?', true]

  # In Rails 3, named scopes are ultra-elegant, and let you do things like:
  scope :with_comments, joins(:comments)
end
```

Is there any way to use AREL, or an otherwise leaner syntax, to define custom associations as elegantly as named scopes?

**update**

I've decided it's not a good idea to put that sort of detail into an association anyway, because associations should always/mostly define the basic relationships between models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions is to put spammy scope on Comments:

```
model Post
  has_many :comments

  scope :with_comments, joins(:comments)
end

model Comment
  scope :spammy, where(:spammy => true)
end
```

This looks a bit cleaner with respect to model responsibilities. Performance-wise it's exactly the same:

```
p.comments.spammy.to_sql
# → SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"
#   WHERE ("comments".post_id = 2) AND ("comments"."spammy" = "t")
```

The added benefit: you can get spammy comments from any other associations.

Comment: Yes I've seen this… I suppose it's not good to call it an "association" anyway since it doesn't define a relationship between two models.

Comment: performance-wise, does this have the same effect as limiting the query through the association?  (beginner here)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there may be a better way, but I know that you can use actual [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) conditions (as opposed to [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://metautonomo.us/2010/05/11/activerecord-relation-vs-arel/)s) in associations by using Arel's [`to_sql`](http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/arel/master/Arel/Nodes/Node#to_sql-instance_method) feature.

```
has_many :spam_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :conditions => Comment.arel_table[:spammy].eq(true).to_sql
```

You'll notice that actual Arel code isn't as lean as ActiveRecord Relations.

I did find [a comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb#L281) in the Rails master branch that referred to passing an Arel predicate as a condition but that code doesn't seem to be in the 3.0 branch. At least not that I could find.