# Rails scope or def based on related table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 application that contains a table called `worequests`.

`worequest.rb` model contains:

```
  belongs_to :statuscode
```

`Statuscodes` has a boolean field called `closed`.

I want to be able to get a list of all `worequests` where `worequest.statuscode.closed == true`.

For example:

```
def index2
  @search = Worequest.closed.search(params[:q])
  @worequests = @search.result
end

OR

worequests.notclosed.count
```

I tried these in the `worequest` model:

```
scope :closed, joins(:statuscode).where(:statuscode.closed => true)
scope :closed, joins(:statuscode).& Statuscode.closed
scope :closed, joins(:statuscode) & Statuscode.closed

def self.closed
  joins(:statuscode) & Statuscode.closed
end

def self.notclosed
  joins(:statuscode) & Statuscode.notclosed
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question is confusing, you say that you have "a Rails 3 table", do you mean that you have a table in a Rails 3 application? The answers are very different depending on if you're using Rails 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Rails 4, named scopes must be given a callable, such as a lambda:

```
scope :closed, -> { joins(:statuscode).where(statuscodes: { closed: true }) }
```

should do the trick (note the singular `:statuscode` in the `join` and the plural `statuscodes` table name in the `where` condition).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly.
Do you just want a scope on your class so you get all closed ones?

```
class StatusCode < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :worequest
end

class Worequest < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :status_code do
    def closed
      where(closed: true)
    end
  end
end

closed_quests: Worequest.all.closed
```

I've based my answer on the question asked here: [How do you scope ActiveRecord associations in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412340/how-do-you-scope-activerecord-associations-in-rails-3)

As this is how I interpreted your question.
For rails 4, I recommend using the other answer.

Comment: Currently Worequest belongs_to :statuscode not the other way round.  Is there a way to do this without changing that?

Comment: you should be able to do the same what I did with the reverse associations. Both take a block, so you can still do the same trick i did.